# How to get callback from user cancelling dialog to select mobile-app after clicking on a link?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I am working with HTML on mobile-devices and want to offer map-routing-functionality.
On mobile devices it makes sense to offer the use the local app, and this is working fine - I do that with changing the

```
location.href
```

Is it possible to get any result from the device-dialog?
I want to forward the user to another function, if he is canceling the dialog-box without selecting an app.

Comment: It's just a guess, but maybe do a setTimeout of a few seconds and see if anything changes?

Answer (score 0):

Create an event handler for the cancel button, would be the most obvious solution to me. But I am not sure if I understand your problem.